# How to add margin to an image inside of custom button

Tags: android, imageview, android-button, material-components-android, custom-button

I have a custom Button with a centered (default) text. I want to add an image just 8dp left of this text which are have to be in custom button.

I can add it only left with `drawableLeft` attribute. I want to make it more centered.

[image]

This is my custom button.

How to make centered that image? (8dp left of text)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `MaterialButton` with the `app:iconGravity` attribute.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
    app:icon="@drawable/...."
    app:iconGravity="textStart"
    android:text="@string/..."
    .../>
```

[image]

You can change the padding between the icon and the text using `app:iconPadding="xxdp"` attribute.

Example with `app:iconPadding="0dp"`:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it possible on custom button? Because my custom button is "com.example.android.custombutton.CustomButton"

Comment: Your `CustomButton` can extend the `MaterialButton` for example